# Run 'pm2 save' after the application is restarted from the --watch flag

Tags: node.js, pm2

So I'm currently running a pm2 application with the watch flag set to true so my application restarts whenever a file is changed. But the process list is never saved (i.e. 'pm2 save' is never ran). I need to current process list to be saved after a file is updated so on machine reboot, the most recent version of the pm2 service is started.

So how do I make it so 'pm2 save' is ran after the watch flag restarts the service? Or am I misunderstanding 'pm2 save' and that doesn't actually need to be ran after each code change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the command `pm2 set pm2:autodump true` was recently added to PM2 that will auto save PM2 on restart/start.

Its not really documented anywhere unfortunately. Hope this helps some people